# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I just deployed my MVC app to a subdomain and I just can't get webapi to work.

Accessing locally:
localhost:40052/api/apiEmpreendimento/GetObjects
works just fine, but accessing the following online:
http://subdomain.mysite.com/api/apiEmpreendimento/GetObjects

Gives me

{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://subdomain.mysite.com/api/apiEmpreendimento/GetObjects'."}

App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Any tip is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You realize your URL has api/api in it, right? Is that right?

Comment: i have the same configuration in my WebApiConfig and have methods name GetLocationCategory which accepts one parameter.. when i run the corresponding path , its giving me error :{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:43433/api/WebApi/GetLocationCategory/87'.

Answer (score 2):

I thought it's about new WepApi. MVC understands it like WebApi controller, Microsoft Reserved Api Controlller for their selves, I changed my Controller name With MyApiController and problem solved.